# Embedding a Jackson JsonNode in POJO stored in CrudRepository

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-data, spring-data-couchbase

Here's where I'm at.  I've an MVC controller method that accepts JSON content.  Because I need to validate it using JSON Schema, my controller maps the request body as a Jackson JsonNode.

Upon successful validation, I need to persist the data in Spring Couchbase repository.  Consider the following snippet:

```
public class Foo
{
    @Id
    private String  _id;

    @Version
    private Long    _rev;

    @Field
    private JsonNode nodeData;

    // .. Other data and members.
}


//
// Repository
//

@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends CrudRepository<Foo, String> {
}
```

When I store these elements into the Couch repository, what I'd like to see is something like this:

```
{
  "_class": "Foo",
  "field1": "field 1 data",
  "nodeData"  : {
    "Some" : "additional data",
    "from"  : "JsonNode"
  }
}
```

instead, what I see in the repository is something like this:

```
{
  "_class": "Foo",
  "field1": "field 1 data",
  "nodeData"  : {
    "_children": {
      "Some": {
        "_value": "additional data",
        "_class": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TextNode"
      },
      "From": {
        "_value": "jsonNode",
        "_class": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TextNode"
      },
    "_nodeFactory": {
      "_cfgBigDecimalExact": false
    }
  }
}
```

Each stored property of the JsonNode is decorated with class information, and other meta-data, which is not desirable.

My question - is there a preferred way to get the CrudRepository to behave in the manner that I wish?

Comment: This may be happening because your "nodeData" class is of instance ObjectNode which has a member variable _children. http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/node/ObjectNode.html 

Create your own bean class or plugin your own serializer

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work that way because serialization and de-serialization conventions are already established. You can override these conventions with custom serialization & de-serialization in Jackson-- but that might go beyond the "crude" approach you are looking for.

I see you want a one shoe fits all approach to data modeling.

Might i recommend storing a Map

```
@Field
private Map<String, String> data;
```

This map is private so its perfect.

You can then have two methods

one method puts to the map like so

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()

public void setFeild(String name, Object value) {

    ObjectNode node new ObjectNode(JsonNodeFactory.instance);
    node.put("clazz", value.getClass().getName());
    if (value instance of String) {
        node.put("value", value)
    } else {
        node.put("value", mapper.writeValueAsString(data));
    }
    data.put(name, node.toString());

}
```

the other gets from the map like so

```
public Object getField(String name) {

     if (data.contains(name)) {
         JsonNode node = mapper.readValue(data.get(name), JsonNode.class);
         Class clazz = Class.forName(node.get("class").textValue());
         if (clazz.equals(String.class) {
             return node.get("value").textValue();
         } else {
              return (Object) mapper.readValue(node.get("value"), clazz);
         }
     }

}
```

You should update this implementation to handle Date, Integer, Boolean, Double ... etc the same way i am handling String-- POJOs are what you serialize/de-serialize to/from json.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for you response.  FWIW, I'm not after a "one shoe fit's all" method for data modeling - my data models are expressed as JSON schema.  The reason I'm not just using POJOs is that I would have to keep them sync'd with the JSON schemas (effectively maintaining 2 schemas).